# Ошибка is not a function React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При выполнении кода выскакивает ошибка `this._changePage is not a function`:

```
_changePage() {
    const login_hash    = UserStore.getTree().getLoginHash();

    if(login_hash){
        if(ApplicationStore.getTree().getPreviousRegistationPageFlag()) {
            Router.goTo('/');
            Actions.setRegistationPageFlag({flag: false});
        } else {
            Router.goBack();
        }
    }
}

isAuthorized(params = {}) {
    const parameters = params.parameters || {};

    if (parameters.in_process === false) {
        this._changePage(); //тут ошибка
    }
}
```

P.s. в гугле видел, что нужно биндить, в итоге добавил код, но не помогло:

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
        this._changePage = this._changePage.bind(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего `isAuthorized` тоже нужно прибиндить, ибо не известно чем там внутри является `this`.

В таких случаях замечательно помогает отладчик.

Comment: заработало, спасибо